# javascript conflict using fancybox and a sandbox menu

Tags: jquery

The problem I have is being tested at [www.provalserv.com/testfsb/test/w3c.html](http://www.provalserv.com/testfsb/test/w3c.html). Mostly the gallery works, but it should work like [www.provalserv.com/testfsb/test/gallery.html](http://www.provalserv.com/testfsb/test/gallery.html) with the images sliding out and back in, not just giving me an image in a white bg.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more detail for those who aren't following the links, e.g. "I expected behavior X, but instead it shows behavior Y"? That will help all of us (including you) understand the problem better.

Comment: pjmorse I do apologize  sorry for being vague,

Comment: my problem seems to be a conflict with the galley script (fancybox) and my navigation bar witch i think is sandbox,  well it must be because if i remove the nav (sandbox) the gallery works as it should, it displays and operates correctly,  but with the nav it displays ok but by clicking on an image it just appears as an image, it doesnt have the sleek slide effect that it does without the nav. does that make sence?